# The response of Authentication grant code is 200 Ok. But not getting the code

Tags: authentication, callback, response, docusignapi, webapi

The response of  Authentication grand code for the request which i pass is 200 Ok. But am getting an html response in that. i couldn't find any code. Can You please help me.?

https://account-d.docusign.com/oauth/auth?response_type=code&scope=signature&client_id=XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXfeeb89&redirect_uri=https://localhost:44330/callback

This is the request which i send. But not receiving the authentication code. But It shows 200 OK.

Comment: Try using Chrome Developer Tools and check the Network table to see what other requests are being made.  You might see some errors which you hadn't accounted for.

Answer (score 0):

In the admin tool, check that your integration key is set to use Authorization Code grant, not Implicit grant.

Also check that you've authorized your exact callback URI for your integration key.

If you're not getting any errors from DocuSign, then authenticate yourself and the your browser will then be redirected to your redirect uri, in this case https://localhost:44330/callback